Nagarjuna and the emptiness of the Dharma
Once Nagarjuna has demonstrated the emptiness of all exaggerated existential positions, including the existence of the Dharma and the Buddha's doctrine, how does he then affirm the validity of the Dharma? Is it because the Dharma teaches nothing other than its own emptiness (as well as the emptiness of everything) and thus is conventionally affirmed as the supreme teaching? Why does the Dharma hold a privileged position?

In fact, this clarification of yours is well done and I should have further specified my question, which is made with a prasangika and Gelug bias. I am asking from a "rangtong" (self-emptiness) point of view, and not from a "shentong" point of view ("emptiness of other", not empty of its very luminosity). But, anyhow, I am delighted to read your way of approaching the question!

I don't know a specific statement he may have used, but the Dharma is likened to a raft you use to cross a river, and when you get to the other side you don't need to pick it up and carry it on your back. A raft would hold a privileged position because rocks and mud don't float.
There's also the metaphor of using a peg to knock another peg out of a hole, then you put down both. "Expedient means" is a related idea, which maintains that something may not be ultimately true, but it's appropriate or useful at the time, or it's true in a relative, conventional way.
These mention the same thing about the raft:
http://www.khandro.net/buddhism_doctrine_Nagarjuna.htm
http://thezensite.com/ZenEssays/Nagarjuna/SecondBuddha_Nagarjuna_Loy.html

Thank you very much, I think you have understood the matter of my question perfectly. As a consequence of what you say, it arises for me how Nagarjuna defends the Dharma as the 'best' doctrine compared to others on a conventional level. I suppose one could say that for him it is the best of the upayas. Do you agree?

Yeah, I think Enlightened people would speak from their own experience, and have different ways of explaining or pointing to, but the knowledge they get is the same, because a thing is what it is, regardless of how different people may describe it. Maybe not a good analogy here, but it reminds me of the blind men and the elephant story. And this seems relevant: "For those with other views, other practices, other satisfactions, other aims, other teachers, it is difficult to know." -MN 72.

I think there is a misunderstanding here. Emptiness is not an end; instead, it should be used as a means to an end which is Nirvana. The Buddha did not teach emptiness as a goal. Nowhere I believe in Nagarjuna’s own writings is the validity of the Dharma ever questioned. Rather Nagarjuna’s writing was to refute erroneous views (perhaps espoused by other religious sects) especially those of two extremes i.e. eternalism and nihilism in/of reality.
